# My file is not readable smarty

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I'm trying to include a PHP file into tpl file
My code:

```
/**{include_php file='Compteur.php'}**/
```

Smarty sh

> **Notice:** Undefined property: SmartyBC::$trusted_dir in /var/www/vhosts/vps143526.ovh.net/my-wall.fr/dev/tools/smarty/Smarty.class.php on line **730**
>
> **Fatal error:** Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template
>   "/var/www/vhosts/vps143526.ovh.net/my-wall.fr/dev/modules/admincreation/admincreation.tpl" on line **58** *"{include_php file='Compteur.php'}"* *{include_php}* file
>   'Compteur.php' is not readable <-- thrown in
>   /var/www/vhosts/vps143526.ovh.net/my-wall.fr/dev/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php
>   on line **58**

How can I resolve this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It could be many things, your file doesn't exists, its path is invalid, you file is read-locked, corrupted or doesn't fits some Smarty requirements to be read (like this `SmartyBC::$trusted_dir` that seems to be unset, but in need to get a value). By the information you provided, you'll have to debug for each of those, unless you have something more to share.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make another solution wich is to insert code directly on my .tpl page

```
 {php}
$monfichier = fopen('{$modules_dir}Compteur.txt', 'r+');
$pages_vues = fgets($monfichier);
$pages_vues++;
fseek($monfichier, 0);
fputs($monfichier, $pages_vues);
fclose($monfichier);
echo '<p>Cette page a été vue ' . $pages_vues . ' fois !</p>';
{/php}
```

But I got another problem:

> Warning: fopen(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/dev/modules/Compteur.txt) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/vps143526.ovh.net/:/tmp/) in /var/www/vhosts/vps143526.ovh.net/my-wall.fr/dev/tools/smarty/SmartyBC.class.php(464) : eval()'d code on line 
>   I know its related to permissions, I have change it to "777" but the error is still here

Comment: please don't use the answers area to place code that belongs in your question. You've done this for most of your questions. If you have another question, then ask another one instead of posting that you have another problem for the same question.

Answer (score 0):

In template engine, use php files to instance variables. Controller in Prestashop.